# Show $||yx^T||_2=||y||_2||x||_2$ for some $x, y\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

> Assume $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. We denote $2$-norm of a vector as $||x||_2$
> meaning: $$||x||_2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n{|x_i|^2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$
> Also assume $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Denote $2$-norm of a matrix
> as $||A||_2$ meaning: $$||A||_2=\underset{||x||_2=1}{\,\,\text{ max
>  }\,\,} ||Ax||_2=\sqrt{\rho(A^TA)}=\sqrt{\rho(AA^T)}=\sigma_1(A),$$
> Which $\rho(A^TA)$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $A^TA$ and
> its square root is the maximum singular value of $A$ or $A^T$.

Now for $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$ show $$||yx^T||_2=||y||_2||x||_2.$$

My try:
$$
yx^T=
\begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\y_2\\\vdots\\y_n
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & \dots & x_n
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
y_1x_1 & y_1x_2 & \dots & y_1x_n\\
y_2x_1 & y_2x_2 & \dots & y_2x_n\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
y_nx_1 & y_nx_2 & \dots & y_nx_n\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$
So we should find $2$-norm of this matrix. Also:
$$||y||_2||x||_2=\sqrt{(y_1^2+y_2^2+\dots y_n^2)(x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots x_n^2)}.$$
But I couldn't find out how to connect these. I tried to calculate $||yx^T||_2$ by multiplying it to a vector with $2$-norm equal to $1$ and finding the maximum $2$-norm, but it wasn't helpful.

Any help or hint is immensely valuable to me!

Comment: your $yx^T$ is a rank-1 matrix. It has one non-zero eigenvalue and everything else zero. Can you find this eigenvalue? Also, [same question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4025929/2-norm-of-a-rank-1-matrix)